# How to mock a POST request with json data using Mockito

Tags: java, json, servlets, junit, mockito

I have the following unit test

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Unit tests for {@link HelloAppEngine}.
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class GroceryServletTest {
  private static final String MOCK_URL = "/grocery";
  // Set up a helper so that the ApiProxy returns a valid environment for local testing.
  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper();

  @Mock
  private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;

  @Mock
  private HttpServletResponse mockResponse;

  private StringWriter responseWriter;
  private GroceryServlet servletUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    helper.setUp();

    //  Set up some fake HTTP requests
    when(mockRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn(MOCK_URL);

    // Set up a fake HTTP response.
    responseWriter = new StringWriter();
    when(mockResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(responseWriter));

    servletUnderTest = new GroceryServlet();
  }

  @After public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void doGetWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    servletUnderTest.doGet(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains("Hello Kitty");
  }

  @Test
  public void doPostWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
    reqObj.put("name", "Beer");
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(reqObj.toString());

    when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(reqObj.toString())));

    servletUnderTest.doPost(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains("Hello Kitty");
  }
}
```

What I can't figure out, is how to post a JSON object as part of the mockRequest in my doPostWritesResponse() test. I would turn an object like the one below into a json object and pass it to the servlet

```
Grocery grocery = new Grocery("Beer");
```

The servlet would read the JSON data from the request something like this

```
  BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
  }
  String jsonString = stringBuffer.toString();
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: How does the code under test read the body of the request? Assuming it reads it from the request's input stream, then mock the getInputStream() method of the request, and make it return a ByteArrayInputStream containing the JSON data.

Comment: @JBNizet I would post the object to the servlet and pass back a response method that I would then assert, if that is what you mean.

Comment: No. What I mean is: how does the code of the servlet read the JSON from the request? Post the code.

Comment: That part hasn't been implemented yet, I wanted to write the test first, and then based on the post request I would store the data. The question has been updated with stub code for reading the json.

Comment: OK. so it's supposed to read the JSON from the request reader. So create a StringReader containing the JSON string, and make the mock request.getReader() return this StringReader .

Comment: Note that StringBuffer is obsolete for a long time, and that all JSON parsers can (or at least should) parse from a Reader or a Stream as argument directly. No need to read lines from the reader.

Comment: I am not sure I get the getReader() part, I have added the JSON object but how do I post it to my servlet?

Comment: You don't post anything to any servlet. You're not writing an integration test. You're writing a unit test where you create your servlet yourself, and call its methods with a mock request and a mock response. So you need to make this mock request.getReader() return a reader containing the JSON: `when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(new StringReader("your json here"));`

Comment: I have updated my test, is that what you mean?

Comment: Not sure why you wrap the STringReader into a BufferedReader. That's useless. And of course, you need to mock the request **before** calling the servlet, not after. Otherwise, when the servlet is called, getReader() will return null.

Comment: but shouldn't the test fail now? It isn't, it is still asserting that the response contains Hello Kitty which isn't the case

Comment: Well, what's the code of the servlet?

Comment: I don't know exactly your problem, but I've fixed for you to pass your case, plz take a look: https://github.com/tvd12/java-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/com/tvd12/javaexample/testing/GroceryServletTest.java, If It's what do you want, I will move it to answer

Comment: @dungtavan if I read the code correctly, the servlet returns what ever is posted to it as json, correct?

Comment: yes, because you did't post your Servlet Content so I must fake one